# Trying to use data from file in mathematical equations

Tags: python, file, csv, python-3.x

I'm not sure what's wrong with this code. It's supposed to allow me to use data from `fitnessfile.csv` in mathematical equations. This is my code:

```
 import csv 
 csvfile = file.open("fitness file.csv")
 readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

 genders = []

 for row in readcsv:
     print (row)
     gender = row[3]

    genders.append(gender)
```

If you have a better or easier way of using data from a file in mathematical equations then please tell me. When I run this code it says

```
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

`file` is in the second line of code

Comment: *"It's supposed to..."* - so **what does it do instead?!** And what about *"DO NOT USE THIS TAG!"* made you think *"yeah, I'll tag this [tag:data]"*?

Comment: Sample Input and Output need

Comment: this is how the file looks like

Comment: test4,16,165.0,45,23.875114784205692,1677.7915000000003 this is how the file looks

Comment: @jonrsharpe as long as the data tag exists, people are entitled to use it.

Comment: @Yousefshihadeh why on earth did you just make up a rough approximation of the error message? It's just text, **copy and paste it**, then use the `{}` button for formatting. And of course you get a `NameError`; the message isn't lying, `file` **isn't** defined! That should just be `csvfile = open(...)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe stick that in an answer.

Comment: it doesnt run the code anymore

Comment: @Yousefshihadeh so now you fix the next problem it's telling you about. Welcome to programming! Read the error message, Google it, do some research.

Comment: it runs the code before the one given ( i didnt include because it has nothing to do with the code given) but then skips this part and carries on to the next piece of code

Comment: @Yousefshihadeh I doubt it *skips* it - however, note that if there's nothing in `"fitness file.csv"` (**really?!**) then there's nothing to `for` loop over and nothing will happen.

Comment: Your error is `file.open("fitness file.csv")` should be `open("fitness file.csv")`

Comment: @dbliss questions like this need closing, not answering: *"you get the error for exactly the reason the message says"* is really **not** useful to anyone but the OP (and barely then), and it's looking like this was the least of their worries...

Comment: @jonrsharpe ha, fair point.  every day my mind is blown anew by the low quality of SO posts.

Comment: @Yousefshihadeh your last comment is unintelligible.

Comment: for the guy that said go do some research. what does it look like im doing research. how am i gonna do research if i cant ask questions @jonsharpe

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but consider:

```
import csv 
with open("fitness file.csv") as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    genders = []
    for row in readcsv:
        print (row)
        gender = row[3]
        # you will probably need to convert 'gender' to float 
        # with float(gender) to use in arithmetic, which I *think* is the question
        genders.append(gender)
```

Comment: when i try to run the code you gave me it doesnt run it (kind of skips it)

Comment: I cannot help you without something to act on. I suggest a python tutorial.